# Markov Chain is irreducible or not, and aperiodic or not.

Tags: stochastic-processes

[image]
states = {1,2,3,4}
I'm confused if the following markov chain is irreducible or not. I think it's not irreducible because if it reaches from one state to another with probability 1 it stays there.  I think it's not aperiodic as there are no self loops.

Answer (score 0):

It sends a variable from state 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1. So it is periodic with period 4. In this case it is also irreducible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just have another question how do i show  P^(n) is equal to 1/4 as the limit approaches infinity. The stationary distribution is given which is (1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4)

Comment: Do you mean when the limit of n goes to infinity? For your understanding, P^(n) is this matrix/markov chain applied to your input n times, note P^1 = P^4 since it is 4 periodic. It is itself another matrix, so it cannot be equal to one number.